# Multiple IP's per domain name and route to fastest available server?

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, nameserver, domain-name

I'm not very familiar with NameServers. Where can I find information or how can I set up multiple servers with different IP's to use the same domain name, such that the client connects to the closest/lowest latency server? I'm having a tough time find the answer to this. It seems like it would be a fairly popular thing to do.

Comment: Can you provide some additional context? What is the "client" and is it aware of any of this or do you need to serve different DNS data based on something (geolocation based on IP?) or something along those lines?

Comment: That's exactly it. The client is the browser or otherwise a general computer connection and I'd like them to connect to the closest server, if possible, to route to the server with the lowest latency in case the geographically closest is not the fastest. It's so my games and other network-type latency-dependent services can be served most quickly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BIND has a GeoIP plugin which, I believe, can allow you to change the response based on the user's location.

An easier solution would be to use Amazon's [Route53](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/) DNS service which supports responding differently in different zones, record/set weighting, etc.

Comment: +1 for Route53. Big time and money saver.

Comment: Are there any keywords for which I can search? And that's great. I haven't had a chance to look into BIND much yet (glanced over it), but it may be what I'm looking for, and I didn't know about Route53, which seems great if I'm in a hurry. Awesome, I was just wondering if there's anything I can search for (GeoIP is a good one).